# Can i move ~/Library/Developer to an external drive?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, mobile

I'm trying to move ~/Library/Developer to an external drive as its taking up about 30gbs on my computer. Is it possible to do so!

Comment: Go to Xcode > preferences > locations and change derived data and archives locations

Comment: @LeoDabus Is it simply just putting those location into my external drive? Or do I need to do some kind of formatting after wards?

Comment: What do you mean by formatting? I would use a mac formatted hard disk (HFS or APFS). Just select the desired directories.

Comment: @LeoDabus by formatting, I mean if I would have to format Xcode or something along those lines. Sorry for not being clear